# How to avoid parens in if to stop pylint errors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pylint

I can understand about the parens on outside `if` could be unnecessary but how to avoid these parens of `len()` functions to stop `Pylint` errors?

```
if len(cart_mail)>40: 
    print("Add to the Database now")
else:
    print("Do not add to the Database now")
```

`Pylint` Error:

```
SSH/main.py:449:0: C0325: Unnecessary parens after 'if' keyword (superfluous-parens)
```

Is there any other convention to bypass the `Pylint` error.
Please help me understand to code this in a better way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the line which is causing the warning message...

Comment: The parens after `len` are required, not superfluous. It shouldn't complain about that line.